# Comment traduire « approved for release » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

> Although the company's "Quality Unit (QU) was aware of the drug
> quality failure, no investigation of manufacturing was performed and
> the lot was **approved for release** to customers." ([FDA Warning
> Letter to US Drug Maker](https://www.gmp-compliance.org/gmp-news/fda-warning-letter-to-us-drug-maker))

Quelles sont des manières de traduire « *[approved](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/approve) for [release](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/release)* » ici ? Va-t-on employer un verbe comme auxiliaire avec « approuver » ? On notera qu'en anglais on a les mots *distribution* et *sale* et qu'on ne les a pas employés ; quel terme va-t-on utiliser et pourquoi ?

Comment: Pour les médicaments, le terme juridique est **autorisation de mise sur le marché**.

Comment: In this case, not exactly. The AMM can be ebtained (as was probably the case here) and  some time later the FDA checks on the manufacturing good practices, and this can happen a long time after the drug has been marketed. I believe @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t 's answer, "mise en circulation", is more adapted to this situation.

Answer (score 3):

En français, "être approuvé pour" + substantif n'est pas la tournure la plus idiomatique. Il est possible d'utiliser "être autorisé à" mais c'est généralement suivi d'un verbe et cela marche mieux quand l'action autorisée est faite par le sujet, comme dans

> L'avion a été autorisé à voler

Ici, cela reviendrait à dire

> ~ Le lot a été autorisé à être mis sur le marché

qui est lourd et bancal.

On transforme souvent un passif en substantif pour rendre une tournure plus naturelle :

> ✔️ Le lot a reçu une autorisation de mise sur le marché

Comme "autorisé à la vente" est une expression qui existe, on peut aussi dire :

> ✔️ Le lot a été autorisé à la vente (au public)

Mais comme relevé dans la question, le sens de "vente" est très légèrement différent et peut-être moins précisément situé dans le processus de commercialisation d'un médicament (qui d'ailleurs est probablement différent dans les pays francophones et aux Etats-Unis, auquel cas la traduction ne sera jamais 100% exacte).

Comment: Est-ce que _mise sur le marché_ signifie la même chose que _mise en marché_ ? Je suis moins familier avec l'emploi de _sur_ ici.

Answer (score 2):

> ...et la [*mise en circulation*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources-linguistiques/chroniques/chroniques-terminologiques/comment-traduire-release-en-francais) du lot a été autorisée.

On trouve aussi ce terme dans d'autres [contextes](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=MISE%20CIRCULATION&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs). Le terme permet de distinguer de la *vente*.